# Android: agrupamiento de notificaciones

Tags: android, notificaciones

Buen día, Tengo un inconveniente y he probado varias opciones pero no obtengo el resultado esperado. Estoy haciendo las notificaciones usando un canal y un grupo, sin embargo, el grupo digamos que sí se realiza pero de una forma media anómala con un tipo de cabecera que "agrupa! las notificaciones con el nombre de la aplicación "app_notificaciones" (imagen 1) pero que a su vez es independiente del resto del grupo de mensajes (imagen 2), es decir podría deslizar y eliminar esa cabecera y no elimina los grupos (imagen 2). La forma como se muestra no es como lo hace Whats app por ejemplo. He probado en terminal físico (S9+ API Q) y virtual (Api29) y da lo mismo. Adjunto imagen de como se muestra. Qué me faltaría por hacer o modificar?

Sobre el código es el mismo que indica la página oficial con las propiedades:

.setGroupSummary(true)

.setGroup(<<Cídigo del grupo>>)

[image: Cabecera del agrupamiento][image: Cabecera independiente del grupo de notificaciones]

Comment: Hago una corrección pues el .SetGroup() no lleva un código,sino,un tag. Añado parte del código. Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Estas notificaciones son creadas usando la clase [NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero esta notificaciòn al parecer esta creada en base a una llamada telefonica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me parece que esa es una razòn por la cual no esta agrupada con las otras notificaciones.

Si deseas que se agrupen, asegura que las notificaciones definan un grupo con la misma llave, en este caso el mismo "còdigo del grupo":

```
.setGroup(<<Còdigo del grupo>>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrección en el .setGroup() no es el código, si no, un string que es un Tag. El código va al momento de lanzar la notificación (notify). El icono de una llamada perdida puede cualquier icono en sí, incluso al tener mismo icono no cambia en nada. Ejemplo código:

```
private final int SUMMARY_GROUP_ID = 1001;
private final String SUMMARY_GROUP_NAME = "GROUPING_NOTIFICATION";

        Notification SummaryNotification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),Channelid)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_missed_call)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setGroup(SUMMARY_GROUP_NAME)
                .build();

        getManager().notify(SUMMARY_GROUP_ID,SummaryNotification);


public NotificationManager getManager(){
    if (manager == null){
        manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    return manager;
}
```